# Highcharts one of the graphs dont appear/plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plot, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts JS. 
I'm finding an issue in plotting "processed_json4".
All the other 4 plots (processed_json to processed_json3) appear on the graph. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have initialised 5 arrays and pushed the data received from JSON file into these arrays. The 5th plot however does not appear.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Highcharts data from JSON Response</title>
  <style>
  body{
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-left:10px;
  }
  </style>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
                var processed_json = new Array();   //TS1
    var processed_json1 = new Array();  //TS2 
    var processed_json2 = new Array();  //TS3
    var processed_json3 = new Array();  //Processing Delay
    var processed_json4 = new Array();  //Input-Output Delay    
                $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/charts_demo/new4.json', function(data) {
                    // Populate series
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     
       
     processed_json.push([data[i].timestamp1, data[i].val]);
     processed_json1.push([data[i].timestamp2, data[i].val]);
     processed_json2.push([data[i].timestamp3, data[i].val]);
     processed_json3.push([((data[i].timestamp3)-(data[i].timestamp2)), data[i].val]);
     processed_json4.push([((data[i].timestamp3)-(data[i].timestamp1)), data[i].val]);
                    }
                 
                    // draw chart
                    $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: "line"
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: "Streaming Flink Data"
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category',
                        allowDecimals: true,
                        title: {
                            text: "Timestamps"
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: "Steps"
                        }
                    },
     
                    series: [{
                     name: 'Timestamp1',
                        data: processed_json
                    },
      {
       name: 'Timestamp2',
       data: processed_json1
     } ,
      {
                     name: 'Timestamp3',
                        data: processed_json2,
                    },
      {
                     name: 'Processing Delay',
                        data: processed_json3,
                    },
      {
                     name: 'Input-Output Delay',
                        data: processed_json4,
                    }
     
     ]
                }); 
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div style="width: 800px; margin: 2em auto; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 0.5em">
 Highcharts data load from a JSON using manual JSON Processing
 </div>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

new4.json looks like this:

[
    {
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718629809",
        "timestamp2": "1272913900562",
        "timestamp3": "1272914212663",
        "val": 0
    },
    {
        "temperSensorData": "26.183021749996204",
        "temperSensorUnit": "celsius",
        "timestamp": "1370718629809",
        "timestamp2": "1272923870899",
        "timestamp3": "1272923910916",
        "val": 1
    },
.
.
.,{}
]

Comment: In your new4.json I cannot find timestamp1 parameter. Mistake in x value inside your series may cause your issue.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Oh yes, i figured that out and thanks so much! :)

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński How to make the plot assign 0,1,2,3.. dynamically along y-axis instead of adding it to my JSON as "val" parameter?

Comment: Hi Inchara, unfortunately I am not sure what you would like to achieve. Maybe you can use some global variable and increment it every time you are using it inside your getJSON?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I got it to work. Thanks so much for your help! :)